# .NET C# Session Variable Not Updating in Safari Browser

Tags: c#, session, safari

I'm having an issue with storing a Guid key in session with Safari. The code works perfectly fine in IE, Chrome, and Firefox, but for some reason Safari is not updating the session variable. Here's an example of the problem:

```
sessionOutputOne.InnerHtml = Session["TopicId"]; //Old topic ID d158e4f2-c0ac-41ce-8798-e936afaf67f8

Session["TopicId"] = someobject.GuidId.ToString();

sessionOutputTwo.InnerHtml = Session["TopicId"]; //Shows new topic Id f72850a4-c29f-4d1e-ab46-7939c097a002
```

If I refresh the page, the first Session["TopicId"] output shows the new Topic Id (f72850a4-c29f-4d1e-ab46-7939c097a002) in every browser EXCEPT Safari, which continues to show the old id (d158e4f2-c0ac-41ce-8798-e936afaf67f8).

I have eliminated the following possibilities based on other stackoverflow threads:

1. There is no page redirect in effect after setting the session variable.
2. The session variable is not being set in an iframe, but there are iframes in the site for google products.
3. I am not trying to store anything complicated in this session variable, just a guid converted to string.
4. Cookies are not disabled in Safari, and I have customers on other Safari browsers experiencing the same issue.

Additional clue on this: the session variable does successfully set when I turn on Safari "Private Browsing" mode.

Thank you in advance for any insights as to what else I can look into.

**Update:**

So the plot grows thicker. I have found a Response.Redirect in my root Default.aspx.cs file that redirects logged in users to a sub-directory. Commenting out this redirect gets the session working properly; however, it does not appear that the redirect is even being hit. If I replace the redirect with Response.End() to kill the response, everything in the site continues to work fine--only the homepage dies if you hit it directly instead of redirecting logged in users to their content.

**Solution**

Thanks to Steven's persistent assistance with my debugging, I was finally able to at least figure out what is happening, if not why. For some reason, Safari touches our root Default.aspx file when loading our Browse Topic page (possibly behind the scenes, somehow). The Default.aspx was redirecting back to the browse topic page without a query string variable. The Browse page would then clear the session variable to set it to the default topicid. Very convoluted, I know. My solutions was to check for the Session["TopicId"] in Default.aspx and let it redirect to the Browse page with the querystring variable since I could not figure out how to prevent Safari from hitting this page.

Comment: Sessions are stored in cookies. Make sure that you don't have cookies disabled in Safari.

Comment: Thanks. I've confirmed there is an asp.net_sessionid cookie being set in the developer tools. I've updated my question to include this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried clearing the cookie and testing that? See if you can clear out the cookie.

```
Session.Remove("TopicId");
```

If you CAN clear the cookie, try resetting the cookie after the clear to the new value.

```
Session.Add("TopicId",someObject.GuidId.ToString());
```

**UPDATE BASED ON USER UPDATE:**
Based on your, have you tried:

```
Response.Redirect(url, false);
```

Adding that parameters (false) does not abort the thread and continues executing code that is on that thread. Let me know the results.

Comment: Thank you for this excellent suggestion. I am able to NULL the session variable out; however, when I try to add the session variable back with the new value, it does not add.

Comment: So the first time you add it, it is fine. The page reloads and the cookie is removed. The page reloads again and it is not there? Try to do it first like this and let me know the results.

Comment: I appreciate the help troubleshooting. This has helped me get additional data on the issue. I have updated my question to reflect my findings.

Comment: Another great suggestion. I went so far as to add the "false" parameter to all my redirects, but it did not solve the issue. Additional logging found that Safari is redirecting to the same page three times, so I'm trying to setup remote debugging to find out why now.

Comment: Is chrome or firefox redirecting multiple times as well (could be unintentional bad behavior)?

Comment: That's what's so strange about this, only Safari is redirecting to the Default.aspx page, where users go when unauthenticated and then redirecting. I have a solution now to account for this. I will update my question with that and mark you as the correct answer for all the help you have provided me. Thank you so much!